# c++ memory management memory allocation on local variables

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

In the following code I allocate many times an array of integers to a pointer. In each call the address of the of the pointer is the same, at least when I run it. If I do not use the `delete [] y` the process will be killed without any exception being thrown. If I add the line the process runs for ever.

My question is, since in both cases (using or not using `delete`) the address of the pointer remains the same between the calls of the function, does this mean that the same space in memory is allocated? If yes why in one case the process is halted and in the other not?

In a more general question, what happens to the memory used for local variables when a function returns? Is memory management strategy different between regular variables and pointers?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
#include<new>

using namespace std;

void foo();

int main()
{
    while(true)
    foo();   
}

void foo()
{
     try{
           int *y=new int[1000];
           printf("%X\n",&y);
           // delete []  y;
      }
     catch(exception &exc){
           cerr<< exc.what();
      }

}
```

Comment: You might find `std::cout` simpler than `printf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the address of the pointer variable, not the address of the allocated area. Try this to see the address of the allocated area:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)y);
```

Comment: Why the conversion to `void*`?

Comment: The conversion to void* is so the code conforms to the standard. It will most likely work anyway on any normal, modern platform, but the corresponding argument to %p is supposed to be of type void*, which is allowed by the standard to have a different internal representation (for example, more bits) than int*.

Answer (score 1):

If you `delete` the pointer, then you *may* get the same value from `new` in each call. If you don't `delete` the pointer, then you will never get the same pointer returned, as the function have to allocate new memory and the system can't reuse some previously deleted memory.

And memory you allocate dynamically stays allocated for the remainder of the process, it's not "local" in the same sense that variables can be local. If you do not free (by using `delete`) the memory then you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

The memory used for local variables when a function returns is reused by the next function call and that next function's local variables.